# symfony 4 NotFoundHttpException by image in public folder

Tags: symfony

**creating symfony project**

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton cars
cd cars
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 public/index.php
composer require annotations
composer require twig
composer require asset
```

**Creating Page**

```
public/image/seta.png

templates/number.html.twig

    <img src="{{asset('image/seta.png')}}">

src/Controller/CarController.php

    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function number()
    {
       return $this->render('number.html.twig');
    }
```

Why does browser show:

```
Symfony Exception > ResourceNotFoundException > NotFoundHttpException
```

No route found for "GET /image/seta.png" (from "http://localhost:8000/")
(Web page doesn't show seta.png)

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: why does symfony show this Exception: ResourceNotFoundException

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? Same issue for me. Did everything correctly what all the comments suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is that the browser can't find the image, as in the path you have given it doesn't exist or isn't accessible to the client. That's what your error is indicating.

You need to confirm that you can access the image through your browser first. If you can't, then I would suggest you start to look at it's location and whether the path you're using corresponds to it's location.

If you're sure the file path is fine and the image exists and that it's named correctly corresponding to what you're calling it, you should then check the file and folder permissions where the image is located so it's accessible.

Comment: running cmd command as adminstrator and calling `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 public/index.php` show same

Answer (score 0):

Please check the HTML, this code rendered.

```
<img src="{{asset('image/seta.png')}}">
```

Comment: Code rendered:
`<img src="/image/seta.png">`

Comment: `NotFoundHttpException` is seen when you access `127.0.0.1:8000/image/seta.png` on browser?
Didn't you make a typo in the file or directory name?

Comment: checked file name and directory name

Answer (score 0):

change

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 public/index.php
```

to

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public
```

Answer (score 0):

Ronald2g is right, you can also try with the web server bundle:

```
composer require server --dev
```

and:

```
php bin/console server:start
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it can help you, but this might help others having a similar issue.

I had the same issue when I was mistakenly using an internal port number (port 42595 in the example below) given in the command line feedback, instead of port 8000:

```
$ symfony server:start --no-tls
  Feb 25 12:25:30 |DEBUG| PHP    Reloading PHP versions 
  Feb 25 12:25:31 |DEBUG| PHP    Using PHP version 7.4.2 (from default version in $PATH) 
  Feb 25 12:25:31 |INFO | PHP    listening path="/usr/bin/php7.4" php="7.4.2" port=42595
  Feb 25 12:25:31 |DEBUG| PHP    started 
  Feb 25 12:25:31 |DEBUG| PHP    PHP 7.4.2 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:42595) started                                                                                                         
 [OK] Web server listening on 8000 http://127.0.0.1:8000 (PHP CLI 7.4.2)
```